# How to measure different time for a request using Prometheus

Tags: javascript, node.js, monitoring, prometheus

I wanted to measure DNS Lookup, TCP Connection, TLS handshake, Time to First Byte and Content Transfer for the same route using Prometheus but I'm not sure how to do it. Should I put those values in different labels and then the value of the metric would hold the entire request time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do that would be as different time series, with labels to differentiate them.

Don't put varying latency amounts in labels, that's event logging rather than metrics. This will perform poorly, and you won't be able to usefully use the latency values.

You may be interested to know that the next version of the blackbox exporter will include these metrics out of the box for HTTP.